# Response containing list of complex types does not appear in metadata view

Tags: servicestack

I have two services, the first of which returns an individual object while the other returns a list of those same objects. I can't figure out why the service which returns a list doesn't show the response type on the metadata view while the response is shown as expected on the other. Otherwise they function fine and return what you'd expect when called directly.

I've tried several ways of defining the list. Conceptually what I just want to do is have something like this: `ListAllResponse : List<ListIndividualResponse>`.

I have a parameterless public constructor on both types and am not using any serialization annotations, although I have tried that as well.

What am I missing?